# Searching an Array for a value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array with this values:

```
(
    (
      John,
      "John.plist",
      active
    ),
    (
      Lucas,
      "Lucas.plist",
      inactive
    )
)
```

What I need is to get the index of the active node.

Here's my code:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@",@"active"];
 NSArray *results = [accounts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

 NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

And it's giving me error. What's wrong? thanks!

Comment: You have arrays inside array. "active" is in the `mainArray[0][2]`

Comment: I know. But this array is dynamic. That's why I need to search for.

Comment: the first thing that hit my mind is use a loop for outer array say counter is `i` and look in subArray[i], get the index of `active`. store it again.

Comment: There's not a easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ in self",@"active"];
NSArray *results = [accounts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

although a better solution would be dictionaries with key/value pairs instead of single strings